# Post initialising a local variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, initialization, nested, do-while

I was about to post a query but I solved it by reworking the code avoiding the issue but not answering it.

So below is an example of what I was wanting to do.

I had a `for loop` inside a `do-while` loop and wanted the `do-while` loop to run until a condition relating to the nested `for loop` was reached. The error I was getting was that `i` wasn't initialised so the `while` condition could not be run, which makes sense.

I was hoping to create a local variable outside the `do-while` loop and initialize it in the nested `for loop`. This obviously wasn't possible in the way I was trying to execute it but is there another way to 'post initialise' a variable in Java?

Also just out of curiosity what languages allow such post initialisation?

```
case 2:
        int i;
        do{
            try{
                for(i=0; i<array.length;i++){               
                    if(...
                }   
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        } while(!array[i].state.equals("X"));
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve it by giving `i` an initial value when you declare it :

```
int i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize de variable i before the do-while.

Inside the do-while loop you can reset the variable. Now you've already made it in the for condition.

On the other hand, I don't know what your code inside for made it and the logic of your algorithm, but I think that it's possible you have a infinite loop if there aren't any element with the state "X". I think that it is very posible indeed (of course depends of your algorithm) to remove the for loop and add the code in the do-while with a i++ and an end condition like this: while(!array[i].state.equals("X") && i < array.lengh);